Power BI dynamically feed dates from date slicer to oracle sql query in Power Query M
I'm new to power bi and trying to teach myself using copilot but I keep running in circles without any outcome. I'd appreciate some help...
I have built my queries to fetch data from an oracle sql server, using a condition
where date >= '' and date < ''
I would like to feed the dates to my query from a date slicer visual. I have created two measures for start and end date which correctly hold these dates from the slicer. But I can't find a way to pass these dates to the power query M editor.
Referencing them directly doesn't work. I've tried python, no go either.
Trying to pass the measure dates to an intermediate table didn't work either, instead of the slicer values it would show the first date of the month and the current date, for start and end date respectively.
I have also tried a different approach, to build my data model by bringing the necessary tables from my oracle sql db inside power bi and then filter them by the dates in the date slicer. But I then I hit another wall.
I have rewritten the custom functions I have in my oracle sql db to power sql. But every time they would be called to refresh the data, they would query the oracle db instead of my local power bi tables.
Any insight would be welcome.

Take a look at Direct Query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery

Thank you I have taken a look at it. So it cannot be done or...?

I see now, so if I use direct query it should be possible. Otherwise I have to import all necessary tables and filter using dax.

Have a read of all the different storage modes here and make sure you create a star schema. Modelling is one of the most important parts of PBI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-storage-mode

@davidebacci thanks. I ended up importing the necessary tables and columns only from a year back till today, so that data will expand on refresh. Then I added my custom functions logic as new calculated columns. Then added measures for the values I want to show in the report. Filtering data via a date slicer works like a charm now.
